# Spliting list item into several items on variable number of space chars in between elements

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I have function that stores list retrieved from Beautiful soup element. List is generated from HTML `li` elements from `ul` which is in some `div` :

```
carPayment=div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()
```

which gives exactly this **one** list item (spaces are intentional):

```
['cache or debit                                                                   credit or loan                                                                   leasing']
```

How do I split this in list with **three elements**?

Take into consideration that this could be longer list. So list should be split on more than 3 spaces.

Final output should be list with three trimmed elements (no spaces before or after):

```
['cache or debit','credit or loan','leasing']
```

I would prefer comprehension answer so something what would go in one line. So far I have this:

```
carPayment=[div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()[0].split('                                    ',) for i in div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()][0]


  ['cache or debit','          credit or loan','           leasing']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on solution while writing this post, so in case someone is using **Beautiful Soup** and want to clean up retrieved list of items (`li`) from unordered list (`ul`) which is in some `div` here is solution:

```
carPayment=[div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()[0].split() for i in div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()][0]
```

which will give you list with trimmed elements:

```
['cache or debit','credit or loan','leasing']
```

This will also clean up list elements from all '\r' characters (carriage return), and the carriage return-newline pairs (\n\r) and also from all unneeded spaces.

And in case if you have dictionary like items in your list than you can do something like this:

```
carUL = section.div.ul.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').splitlines()[0]
carUL = [i.strip() for i in carUL.split('  ') if i]
```